# Cuban Standards

Tags: theory, sheet-music, musicology, latin-jazz

I know that some of cuban songs are listed in Jazz standards but are there any list of cuban standars that one should follow to learn harmonics and theory about boleros and other genres affiliated to latin music (Also all  of latin music)? Because when I searched it there are quite few information about songs like Veinte Años and other boleros. I am especially curious about If is there any such book on musics like Buena Vista Social club does.

**EDIT :** For cuban jazz I found [this](http://www.thejazzpianosite.com/jazz-piano-lessons/jazz-genres/afro-cuban-latin-jazz/) but still could not find a satisfying resource for overall music of cuba (like trova, bolero etc.)

**EDIT 2:** It seems like (from reviews) [this book](http://www.thejazzpianosite.com/jazz-piano-lessons/jazz-genres/afro-cuban-latin-jazz/) covers it all. I will look up on it. For those who are interested in it seems fairly enough.

**EDIT 3:**  [This](https://archive.org/details/TheLatinRealBook/mode/2up) book is open to public and includes many of latin jazz. Still looking for various books but these 3 resources seems fairly enough when combined.

**EDIT 4:** [This one](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1525/j.ctt1ppkc2) looks quite informative too from review of sections.

I think when these are all combined it is all informative and enough. I will not close the question because there may be new suggestions.

**EDIT 5:**
For those who only look for Latin Jazz Standards here is list [from](https://www.halleonard.com/product/240138/the-latin-real-book):
But still could not find a songbook for other genres.

**EDIT 6:** [This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0793593042) book looks OK for boleros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a VERY abridged list that I threw together for you of some tunes that are considered Cuban standards. They may not all be by Cuban composers. Some of the most famous boleros associated with Cuban singers are often written by Mexican composers like Armando Manzanero. Some of these tunes can be found in the “Latin Real Book” you mentioned and posted. I hope this is helpful, sorry for the lack of caps in the song titles, I’m a little pressed for time today. Feel free to comment if you want to discuss this further.

cachita

pare cochero

bilongo

rico vacilón

son de la loma

decídete

piel canela

frenesí

lágrimas negras

tu mi delirio

obsesión

contigo en la distancia

dos gardenias

Guantanamera

Comment: Thank you a lot. I think it is all enough and will do the job.